# Text Above Image CSS Z-Index Not Working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to force the text above the image, however, It doesn't want to work, I have tried z-index 100 on the text and -100 on the image, but It still doesn't work...

Main HTML:

```
<div class="menu-defaults menu-overlay">
        <div class="menu-container">
            <div class="menu-gallery">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="menu-gallery-options">
                        <div class="menu-gallery-options-title">
                            <span class="gallery-options-title-style" style="z-index: 1;">HOME</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-gallery-options-img">
                            <img src="data/_img/static_ex.jpg" style="z-index: -1;" class="gallery-options-img-style">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Main CSS:

```
    .menu-defaults{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.menu-container{
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu-gallery{
    margin-top: 160px;
}
.menu-gallery-options{
    width: 460px;
    height: 259;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.menu-gallery-options-title{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.gallery-options-title-style{
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-gallery-options-img{
    margin: -45px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.gallery-options-img-style{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I have looked high and low but can't find anything.. :(
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably using `position and z-index` will help check this snippet

```
.menu-gallery-options-title{
  position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```css
    .menu-defaults{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.menu-container{
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu-gallery{
    margin-top: 160px;
}
.menu-gallery-options{
    width: 460px;
    height: 259;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.menu-gallery-options-title{
  position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
  z-index:999;
}
.gallery-options-title-style{
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-gallery-options-img{
    margin: -45px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.gallery-options-img-style{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-defaults menu-overlay">
        <div class="menu-container">
            <div class="menu-gallery">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="menu-gallery-options">
                        <div class="menu-gallery-options-title">
                            <span class="gallery-options-title-style" style="z-index: 1;">HOME</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-gallery-options-img">
                            <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" style="z-index: -1;" class="gallery-options-img-style">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you cannot just swap the order of the title and image elements, so you are forced to use css positioning.

Here is a **live example** with both elements `position: relative` (so that they respect z-index) and with a z-index set on the image:

```css
.menu-defaults{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.menu-container{
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu-gallery{
    margin-top: 160px;
}
.menu-gallery-options{
    width: 460px;
    height: 259;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.menu-gallery-options-title{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.gallery-options-title-style{
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-gallery-options-img{
    margin: -45px 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
.gallery-options-img-style{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-defaults menu-overlay">
        <div class="menu-container">
            <div class="menu-gallery">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="menu-gallery-options">
                        <div class="menu-gallery-options-title">
                            <span class="gallery-options-title-style" style="z-index: 1;">HOME</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-gallery-options-img">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5LGqY2p.jpg?1" style="z-index: -1;" class="gallery-options-img-style">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```