# Place text centrally over image

Tags: html, css

I'd like to place my H2 text vertically & horizontally center over my image.

Can someone explain how I do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/q3odxfmb/

```html
<div class="content">

<img src="http://placehold.it/940x510">
<h2>
TEXT WILL GO HERE
</h2>

</div>
```

Comment: this is a better option https://jsfiddle.net/q3odxfmb/1/ @michaelmcgurk

Comment: Sure is - getting green ticked post haste ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fiddlehttps://jsfiddle.net/q3odxfmb/1/

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
}

#text-outer {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 75%;
}

#text-inner {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

this question already asked so many times please refer this link

**thank you all**

[Text Above Image CSS Z-Index Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376035/text-above-image-css-z-index-not-working/35376080#35376080)

Comment: happy to help you :) @michaelmcgurk

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy. Simply set css to:

```
.h2 {
line-height:/*height of your image*/
}
```

Then set the margin in the div to auto:

```
div {
    background-url: <image-link>;
    margin:auto
}
```

This should center it perfectly.

You would have to have a small margin set for this method.

Here is a JSBin with an easy method, too:
https://jsbin.com/vawowebolu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: No problem, I've updated the answer with a JSBin for another simple way to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

set the text as a background over a div, and center the text over the div.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <h2 id="mytext">
    TEXT WILL GO HERE
    </h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background: url("<image-link>")
}

#mytext {
    line-height: 510px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Vertical align and line height are both essentially doing the same thing, here. I'd use one or the other, preferably line-height, as it won't affect other elements in the div. More specificity allows for greater finite manipulation and flexibility in complicated pages.

Comment: Unless line height is set to height of div, vertical-align won't seem to work. You could probably remove vertical-align, but you'll have to use line-height.

Comment: Yes exactly. Line height is usually the way to go in these situations! Vertical align used to be used a LOT! But it works better if you know for sure there is a single child element in a parent div.