# Marginating an div with content over an image (with z-index) not working as expected

Tags: html, css

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npehfftp/)

So as seen in the Jsfiddle (You may need to hold ctrl + a) I'm trying to achieve having the div on top of the image, but I tried using a `z-index` for both the div and the image, and even put the image in a div by itself, but it still hasn't worked.

I was wondering if this is possible in CSS.

Comment: add `position: absolute` and remove that margin on the div other wise you won't see div contents.

Comment: I believe you are trying to create a design of a text above image? if yes, then you can also check this [question asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376035/text-above-image-css-z-index-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that by default elements are positions statically which means that z-indexes do not apply. Change to a different position such as relative or absolute will make z-index apply.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values

Comment: Thanks for the help :)